# Use @odata.nextLink from Ms graph Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I'm using the following code

```
const users: MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);

users
  .api("/users")
  .select("displayName,mobilePhone,mail,photo,department,jobTitle,mailNickname,loginName")
  .top(10)
  .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
```

Since I'm using `.top(10)` and have more user than 10 I automatic get `@odata.nextLink` and that contains the url to get the next 10 people.

More [documentaion is found here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/paging)

But I'm unable to find a way that I'm allowed to call/use the url.

In the documentaion it states: `You can retrieve the next page of results by sending the URL value of the @odata:nextLink property to Microsoft Graph.`

Can anyone tell me how I can do the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send a request to the `"@odata.nextLink"` URL, you will have the next 10 users. 
It has the parameters in the URL... try something like (only to test it i wouldnt let like that and i wouldn't call MSGraphClient var as "users"):

```
    const users: MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);

    users
        .api("/users")
        .select("displayName,mobilePhone,mail,photo,department,jobTitle,mailNickname,loginName")
        .top(10)
        .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {

            users.api(response[@odata:nextLink]).get((error2,response2: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
                // do stuff
            });
        });
```

I am not sure if you need to remove the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` from string `response[@odata:nextLink]`...